# Find next input element in DIV using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The API method I am using takes a list of parameters in the form of `Dictionary<string,string>`. I am building the inputs for this dynamically with JavaScript, where I have a DIV row and then two inner DIV cells, one for the parameter name and one for the parameter value input.

I can use .each() to loop through each of the parameter name DIVs but need to figure out how to get the value of the input which is displayed directly after it.

With the following pseudo code to show the idea, what would be the best approach where I could get the parameter values together?

CSS Table:

```
consumedValues.innerHTML += "<div class='valuesRow'>";
consumedValues.innerHTML += "<div class='valuesCellName'>" + consumesItem + "</div><div class='valuesCellValue'><input type='text'></div>";
consumedValues.innerHTML += "</div>";
```

Parameter Dictionary:

```
var parameters = {};

$('.valuesCellName').each(function(index)
{
    parameters[$(this).html()] = "INPUT_VALUE_HERE";
});
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by CSS Table, but that's not CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they are siblings, Use [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
$(this).next().find("input").val()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Definitely still learning all of this stuff when it comes to JS/Jquery and that is very nice. I will accept as soon as the time has passed